# Why does the HTML downloaded by WebClient differ from Chrome's "View Source" page?

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm using the following code to download the given web page.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    using (Stream data = client.OpenRead("https://www.yellowpages.com/south-jordan-ut/plumbers?page=5"))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data))
    {
        string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

It works but `html` appears to contain only a small portion of the final page. I understand that this site has dynamic content, but when I view the source code in Chrome (by selecting the *View page source* command), it appears to download everything.

Unless Chrome actually runs scripts when you run *View page source*, it seems to be using some other trick to get all the HTML. Does anyone know what that trick might be?

Comment: When you ask WebClient to downloads the html, it downloads the source before any rendering is done. By the time you are able to go to "View page source" in Chrome, the entire page has been downloaded and rendered.

Comment: @MatthewBrubaker: That shouldn't be the case. In Chrome, there is a specific URL for viewing the source code. (In this case, *view-source:https://www.yellowpages.com/south-jordan-ut/plumbers?page=5*). That should be separate from whether or not I have the page open in another tab.

Comment: @MatthewBrubaker - OP is referring to "View Page Source" (as in CTRL+U in chrome), not "Inspect Page" (CTRL + Shift + I in chrome)

Comment: @gunr2171: Yes, of course. I acknowledged in my question that the site has dynamic content. What I don't understand is why it all appears when I view the source in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you read the HTML that the webClient is returning, you can see some text:

> We can provide you with the best experience on Yellowpages.com, if you upgrade to the latest version of your browser"

If you change your `user-agent` to something that `Chrome` would send, you get the results as expected:

```
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36");
```

Comment: Beat me by 5 seconds ;) Side note: not setting *any* UA at all seems to do the trick as well.

Comment: That appears to be the issue. Running some additional tests.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an ajax call or something similar to load the page data. It's a modern software paradigm whereas before the page would contain all the data already for the data. Whet everyone else is saying is that if there IS javascript to load the content then the webclient would not be able to load this content. This is why you see it in your browser and not the webclient.

The solution is to use another tool like Selenium to download the page into a rendering engine & then scrape what you need.

Comment: I thought I addressed this in my original question, and also the comments. I understand there is dynamic content. What I don't understand is why Chrome seems to have the entire page when it is just displaying the source.

Comment: The source is changing dynamically. Chrome seems to have everything because it changed the original source.

Navigate to https://www.yellowpages.com/south-jordan-ut/plumbers?page=5
Open up the network explorer (f-12) and refresh the page

You will see plumbers?page=5 at the top.

If you look at the response, you will see what your webclient sees. There is no plumber data.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but when you select *View page source* in Chrome, no scripts are run, and that tab is completely separate from any other tabs. I've marked the answer that had the correct solution.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was trying to explain. The http response from the original web request shows what you describe, which you can find in the network tab when you reload the page. Glad you could fix the issue though.